# Fastest way to replace occurences in small string using span in c#

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to maximize the cpu performance and memory optimization for string.Replace method in C#.
The goal is to reduce memory allocation and cpu time as the project is in asp.net core with 10000 rps.

I found out two tips for improve performance:
1)use Span Struct
2)use String.Create

```
   internal struct ContextData
    {
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string Replace { get; set; }
        public string With { get; set; }
    }




    internal string SpanReplaceWithCreate(ContextData context)
    {
        int count = 0;
     
        ReadOnlySpan<char> origin_span = context.Origin.AsSpan();
        ReadOnlySpan<char> replace_span = context.Replace.AsSpan();
        ReadOnlySpan<char> replace_with = context.With.AsSpan();

        int index;
        ReadOnlySpan<char> tmp = origin_span;

        while ((index = tmp.IndexOf(replace_span)) > 0)
        {
            count++;
            tmp = tmp.Slice(index + replace_span.Length, tmp.Length - replace_span.Length - index);
        }

        string a = string.Create(context.Origin.Length + (context.Replace.Length - context.With.Length) * count, context, (chars, state) =>
           {
               // NOTE: We don't access the context variable in this delegate since 
               // it would cause a closure and allocation.
               // Instead we access the state parameter.

               // will track our position within the string data we are populating
               var position = 0;
               ReadOnlySpan<char> origin = state.Origin.AsSpan();
               ReadOnlySpan<char> replace = state.Replace.AsSpan();
               ReadOnlySpan<char> with = state.With.AsSpan();

               ReadOnlySpan<char> tmp_context = origin;

               while ((index = tmp_context.IndexOf(replace)) > 0)
               {
                   tmp_context.Slice(0, index).CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
                   with.CopyTo(chars.Slice(position + index));
                   position += (index + with.Length);
                   tmp_context = tmp_context.Slice(index + replace.Length, tmp_context.Length - replace.Length - index);
               }

               if (position < chars.Length) {
                   tmp_context.CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
               }

           });


        return a;
    }
```

but i still have worst performance compared to the string.Replace

| Method | URL | find | replace | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Rank | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StringReplace | http(...)ogle [196] | google | afd | 370.4 ns | 9.37 ns | 27.33 ns | 360.7 ns | 1 | 0.0319 | - | - | 336 B |
| StringReplaceWithCreate | http(...)ogle [196] | google | afd | 492.8 ns | 9.60 ns | 12.15 ns | 490.4 ns | 2 | 0.0563 | - | - | 592 B |

Any suggestion?

here params for test

```
https://www.example.com/xxxxx?campaign={camp}&adgroup={publisher_id}&install_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{transaction}&session_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{aff_sub1}&affsite={aff_site}&clickid={transaction}&adset_id={creative_id}&user_agent={ua}&ip={ip}&language={lang}



{camp} : "campiagn_it_banner_size_360"
{publisher_id} : "78983"
{transaction} : "c1032072-f815-413b-a57c-4a027f681e60"
{aff_sub1} : "78bea32a-6ead-4ea0-b9f2-9489ebc43d6a"
{aff_site} : "vbvsdgdavhdgdvjs_46_789-p90"
{creative_id} : "360x360"
{ua} : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
{ip} : "192.168.1.1"
{lang} : "en"
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
[Benchmark]
    public string FastTokenReplace()
    {

        string request = "http://wwww.example.com?a=campiagn_it_banner_size_360&b=78983&h=c1032072-f815-413b-a57c-4a027f681e6&y=78bea32a-6ead-4ea0-b9f2-9489ebc43d6a&ty=vbvsdgdavhdgdvjs_46_789-p90&yhhh=360x360&sua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F90.0.4430.93%20Safari%2F537.36&ppp=192.168.1.1";
        string redirecturl = "https://www.example.com/xxxxx?campaign={camp}&adgroup={publisher_id}&install_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{transaction}&session_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{aff_sub1}&affsite={aff_site}&clickid={transaction}&adset_id={creative_id}&user_agent={ua}&ip={ip}&language={lang}&ieruiero{343454";

        int max_allocation = Math.Max(request.Length, redirecturl.Length) * 3;

        return string.Create(max_allocation, redirecturl, (chars, state) =>
        {
            ReadOnlySpan<char> tmp = state.AsSpan();
            int position = 0;
            int placeholder_start;
            while ((placeholder_start = tmp.IndexOf('{')) > 0)
            {
                int placeholder_end = tmp.Slice(placeholder_start).IndexOf('}');
                if (placeholder_end < 0)
                {
                    //copy the last part
                    tmp.CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    tmp.Slice(0, placeholder_start).CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
                    ReadOnlySpan<char> replace = tmp.Slice(placeholder_start, placeholder_end + 1);

                    //OPTIMIZE HERE?
                    ReadOnlySpan<char> with = Placeholders.getVal(replace.ToString()).AsSpan();

                    with.CopyTo(chars.Slice(position + placeholder_start));
                    position += (placeholder_start + with.Length);
                    tmp = tmp.Slice(placeholder_start + replace.Length, tmp.Length - replace.Length - placeholder_start);
                }

            }

        });
    }

 class Placeholders
{



    public const string camp = "{camp}";
    public const string publisher_id = "{publisher_id}";
    public const string creative_id = "{creative_id}";
    public const string ua = "{ua}";
    public const string lang = "{lang}";
    public const string ip = "{ip}";
    public const string Transaction = "{transaction}";
    public const string AffSite = "{aff_site}";
    public const string AdsetId = "{adset}";
    public const string AffSub1 = "{affsub1}";


    public static string getVal(string key)
    {

        switch (key)
        {
            case camp:
                return "campiagn_it_banner_size_360";
            case publisher_id:
                return "78983";
            case Transaction:
                return "c1032072-f815-413b-a57c-4a027f681e60";
            case AffSub1:
                return "78bea32a-6ead-4ea0-b9f2-9489ebc43d6a";
            case AffSite:
                return "vbvsdgdavhdgdvjs_46_789-p90";
            case creative_id:
                return "360x360";
            case ua:
                return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36";
            case ip:
                return "192.168.1.1";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    public static ReadOnlySpan<char> getVal(ReadOnlySpan<char> key)
    {

        if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(key, camp, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return "campiagn_it_banner_size_360".AsSpan();
        else if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(key, publisher_id, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return "78983".AsSpan();
        else if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(key, Transaction, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return "c1032072-f815-413b-a57c-4a027f681e6".AsSpan();
        else if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(key, AffSub1, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return "78bea32a-6ead-4ea0-b9f2-9489ebc43d6a".AsSpan();
        else if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(key, AffSite, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return "vbvsdgdavhdgdvjs_46_789-p90".AsSpan();
        else if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(key, creative_id, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return "360x360".AsSpan();
        else if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(key, ua, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36".AsSpan();
        else if (MemoryExtensions.Equals(key, ip, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return "192.168.1.1".AsSpan();
        else
            return "".AsSpan();


    }




}
   [Benchmark]
    public string StandardTokenReplace()
    {

        string request = "http://wwww.example.com?a=campiagn_it_banner_size_360&b=78983&h=c1032072-f815-413b-a57c-4a027f681e6&y=78bea32a-6ead-4ea0-b9f2-9489ebc43d6a&ty=vbvsdgdavhdgdvjs_46_789-p90&yhhh=360x360&sua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F90.0.4430.93%20Safari%2F537.36&ppp=192.168.1.1";
        string redirecturl = "https://www.example.com/xxxxx?campaign={camp}&adgroup={publisher_id}&install_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{transaction}&session_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{aff_sub1}&affsite={aff_site}&clickid={transaction}&adset_id={creative_id}&user_agent={ua}&ip={ip}&language={lang}&ieruiero{343454";
        int max_allocation = Math.Max(request.Length, redirecturl.Length) + Math.Abs(request.Length - redirecturl.Length);

        //get original url and take the longest one + domain


        return redirecturl.Replace(Placeholders.camp, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.camp))
            .Replace(Placeholders.publisher_id, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.publisher_id))
            .Replace(Placeholders.creative_id, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.creative_id))
            .Replace(Placeholders.ua, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.ua))
            .Replace(Placeholders.lang, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.lang))
            .Replace(Placeholders.ip, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.ip))
            .Replace(Placeholders.Transaction, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.Transaction))
            .Replace(Placeholders.AffSite, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.AffSite))
            .Replace(Placeholders.AdsetId, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.AdsetId))
            .Replace(Placeholders.AffSub1, Placeholders.getVal(Placeholders.AffSub1));

    }
```

**1 MAX ALLOCATION**

```
    int max_allocation = Math.Max(request.Length, redirecturl.Length) * 3;
```

we can calculate the correct size of the string but it will perform worse.
for this case we can assume a max lenght.

[www.example.com?camp=1234567890123456789023456789012345678902345678](http://www.example.com?camp=1234567890123456789023456789012345678902345678)
[www.replace.com?{camp}{camp}{camp}{camp}{camp}{camp}{camp}](http://www.replace.com?%7Bcamp%7D%7Bcamp%7D%7Bcamp%7D%7Bcamp%7D%7Bcamp%7D%7Bcamp%7D%7Bcamp%7D)

won't work.

**2 GETTING VALUE**

```
   ReadOnlySpan<char> with = Placeholders.getVal(replace.ToString()).AsSpan();
```

in case of the placeholder is repeated we can cache the value or search fol all occurences before move to the next placeholder.

**public static string getVal(string key)  vs public static string getVal(ReadOnlySpan key)**

we still have better perfomance using the string version. Any suggestion to improve it?

// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19041.928 (2004/?/20H1)
Intel Core i9-10900 CPU 2.80GHz, 1 CPU, 20 logical and 10 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.202
[Host]        : .NET Core 3.1.14 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.16201, CoreFX 4.700.21.16208), X64 RyuJIT
.NET Core 3.1 : .NET Core 3.1.14 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.16201, CoreFX 4.700.21.16208), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET Core 3.1  Toolchain=.NET Core 3.1

| Method | URL | find | replace | Mean | Error | StdDev | Rank | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FastTokenReplace | [196] |  |  | 518.8 ns | 4.63 ns | 3.61 ns | 1 | 0.2470 | 0.0038 | - | 2.52 KB |
| FastTokenReplaceImproveMem | [196] |  |  | 584.4 ns | 6.84 ns | 5.71 ns | 2 | 0.2050 | 0.0010 | - | 2.09 KB |
| StandardTokenReplace | [196] |  |  | 4,242.7 ns | 84.82 ns | 94.27 ns | 3 | 0.6866 | - | - | 7.06 KB |

Comment: What is the max length of your strings? You may also try using arrays of chars.

Comment: strings are all marketing url, usually less than 300, max 1000. We need to do up to 15 replacement for string based on the number of placeholder

Comment: Optimizing `String.Replace` is likely not the way to go. More productive is optimizing the context so `String.Replace` isn't called in the first place. For instance, expanding placeholders in strings is best done not by taking the original string and replacing, but by parsing it for placeholder delimiters and building up a new string as you go along (a `StringBuilder` is easiest for that, but that could be further optimized with `Span`s if required -- only if required though, as `StringBuilder` is already quite well optimized).

Comment: @Jeroen that's basically what I'm doing in the function. Get the index and rebuild string using span inside a string.create

Comment: Except that doing this 15 times in a row for different placeholders is less efficient than just using a single buffer for all the placeholders at once. Notably, you want to avoid (re)allocating as much as possible. You're currently optimizing for the scenario where a single placeholder occurs many times, but is that correct? Typically the common scenario would be replacing multiple placeholders just one time. Another not unimportant consideration is: do you really need a new string as the output? Could you stream the result directly, for example?

Comment: Ok make sense, actually the placeholder are different but could be repeated in the string. So you suggest to build an index with all placeholder pointer right? I need to check if I can redirect without allocating a string

Comment: As a first approximation, I would simply allocate one `StringBuilder` (for everything) and use its `.Replace` to see if this is already fast enough. You can play with the constructor's `capacity` parameter  if you already know the output will likely be larger than the default. You can precalculate the exact capacity to use with an initial pass through the string, but that may not always be faster. If that isn't enough you can step through the original string with `.IndexOf` and only `.Append` to the builder. Only when that's not fast enough either should you consider messing around with spans.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and replacements for testing?

Comment: @JeroenMostert the stringbuilder allocation seems to be really heavy for cpu. it's 4 time more expensive than multiple string replace in terms of CPU but in terms of memory is 3 times better

Answer (score 2):

Running some tests using the sample data, it seems `String.Replace` is highly optimal, and both `StringBuilder.Replace` and a variation of my `IndexOfAny` that returns which match was found first (based on improvements from CodeReview) are slower. Using an array of tuples for the replacements was fastest of my tests:

```
var s = "https://www.example.com/xxxxx?campaign={camp}&adgroup={publisher_id}&install_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{transaction}&session_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{aff_sub1}&affsite={aff_site}&clickid={transaction}&adset_id={creative_id}&user_agent={ua}&ip={ip}&language={lang}";

var replacementsa = new[] {
        ("{camp}", "campiagn_it_banner_size_360"),
        ("{publisher_id}", "78983"),
        ("{transaction}", "c1032072-f815-413b-a57c-4a027f681e60"),
        ("{aff_sub1}", "78bea32a-6ead-4ea0-b9f2-9489ebc43d6a"),
        ("{aff_site}", "vbvsdgdavhdgdvjs_46_789-p90"),
        ("{creative_id}", "360x360"),
        ("{ua}", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"),
        ("{ip}", "192.168.1.1"),
        ("{lang}", "en")
    };

public static string MultiReplace(this string s, (string match,string replace)[] replacements) {
    for (int replacementNum = 0; replacementNum < replacements.Length; ++replacementNum)
        s = s.Replace(replacements[replacementNum].match, replacements[replacementNum].replace);

    return s;
}
```

Comment: few concern about your code:
1)var type will increase overhead at runtime
2)why we should use tuples and not a dictionary instead?
3)s = s.Replace() will lead in a lot of allocation

Comment: @Riccardo 1) You are incorrect about `var` type - see [C# documentation on var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) 2) Since we are not looking up by key but processing all values, a `Dictionary` just adds overhead and allocation compared to `ValueTuple`. Use `List<T>` if dynamic changes needed. 3) Only once per replacement, but it is faster than alternatives with `StringBuilder` or `Span` because it is optimized library code so which is more important, memory allocation or speed?

Comment: 1) my bad you're right. 2)in real environment you will have a request.query that should be a dictionary. I'll compare switch, dictionary and your solution.3) I'm trying to get the best solution in term of CPU and memory. I will run a test comparison with my solution. But until know parsing span.indexof + slice + string.create is 10 times better than multiple replace

Answer (score 1):

The builtin method should be as optimized as it gets, so trying to make a general Replace function that is faster than that is unrealistic. Maybe using unsafe code and/or a dll written in something like C/C++ could get close. That said, if you create a function that works for you specific constraints, you may be able to squeeze something more performance. From your examples there're 3 potential ways to do the job faster:

- Instead of replacing tokens one at a time, replace them all in a batch. This, of course, assumes taht you don't depend on recursive replacement, otherwise, this won't work for you.
- Assuming evey token that needs to be replaced has the same delimiters, you can greatly reduce calls to `IndexOf`.
- If you can guess the upper bound of the resulting length, you may skip computing the length and just preallocate memory.

Here are the results of my benchmarks (AMD Ryzen 9 5950X):

| Method | Mean | Ratio | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Normal | 875.4 ns | 1.00 | 8.02 KB | 1.00 |
| BatchNaive | 5,512.5 ns | 6.32 | 1.14 KB | 0.14 |
| BatchNaiveCached | 2,838.7 ns | 3.24 | 1.47 KB | 0.18 |
| BatchCached | 964.8 ns | 1.10 | 1.47 KB | 0.18 |
| BatchDelimiterCached | 312.8 ns | 0.36 | 1.47 KB | 0.18 |
| BatchDelimiterPreallocated | 266.0 ns | 0.30 | 2.5 KB | 0.31 |
| BatchDelimiterPreallocatedSafe | 255.6 ns | 0.29 | 2.5 KB | 0.31 |

As you can see, the last three are about 3 times faster for your example. Not only that, but they also use much less (heap) memory.

Here's the code:

- BatchDelimiterCached

```cs
const string origin = "https://www.example.com/xxxxx?campaign={camp}&adgroup={publisher_id}&install_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{transaction}&session_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{aff_sub1}&affsite={aff_site}&clickid={transaction}&adset_id={creative_id}&user_agent={ua}&ip={ip}&language={lang}";

var replaceTasks = new (string, string)[]
{
    ("camp", "campiagn_it_banner_size_360"),
    ("publisher_id", "78983"),
    ("transaction", "c1032072-f815-413b-a57c-4a027f681e60"),
    ("aff_sub1", "78bea32a-6ead-4ea0-b9f2-9489ebc43d6a"),
    ("aff_site", "vbvsdgdavhdgdvjs_46_789-p90"),
    ("creative_id", "360x360"),
    ("ua", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"),
    ("ip", "192.168.1.1"),
    ("lang", "en")
};
char prefix = '{';
char postfix = '}';
// the above are arguments to the funtion

ReadOnlySpan<char> tmp = origin;

// we store the occurences in the queue while calculating the length of the final string
// so we don't have to search for them the 2nd time later
var occurrences = new Queue<(int at, int task)>();
int offset = 0;
int resultLength = tmp.Length;

int prefixIndex;
while ((prefixIndex = tmp.IndexOf(prefix)) != -1)
{
    (int at, int task) next = (prefixIndex, -1);
    for (int i = 0; i < replaceTasks.Length; i++)
    {
        // we expect the postfix to be at this place
        int postfixIndex = prefixIndex + replaceTasks[i].toReplace.Length + 1;
        if (tmp.Length > postfixIndex // check that we don't cross the bounds
            && tmp[postfixIndex] == postfix // check that the postfix IS were we expect it to be
            && tmp.Slice(prefixIndex + 1, postfixIndex - prefixIndex - 1).SequenceEqual(replaceTasks[i].toReplace)) // compare all the characters in between the delimiters
        {
            next.task = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (next.task == -1)
    {
        // this delimiter character is just part of the string, so skip it
        tmp = tmp.Slice(prefixIndex + 1);
        offset += prefixIndex + 1;
        continue;
    }

    int newStart = next.at + replaceTasks[next.task].toReplace.Length + 2;
    tmp = tmp.Slice(newStart, tmp.Length - newStart);

    occurrences.Enqueue((next.at + offset, next.task));
    offset += newStart;

    resultLength += replaceTasks[next.task].replaceWith.Length - replaceTasks[next.task].toReplace.Length - 2;
}

string result = string.Create(resultLength, (replaceTasks, occurrences), (chars, state) =>
{
    var replaceTasks = state.replaceTasks;
    var occurrences = state.occurrences;

    var position = 0;

    ReadOnlySpan<char> origin = origin;
    int lastStart = 0;

    while (occurrences.Count != 0)
    {
        (int at, int task) next = occurrences.Dequeue();

        origin.Slice(lastStart, next.at - lastStart).CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
        replaceTasks[next.task].replaceWith.CopyTo(chars.Slice(position + next.at - lastStart));
        position += next.at - lastStart + replaceTasks[next.task].replaceWith.Length;
        lastStart = next.at + replaceTasks[next.task].toReplace.Length + 2;
    }

    origin.Slice(lastStart).CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
});

return result;
```

- BatchDelimiterPreallocatedSafe

```cs
const string origin = "https://www.example.com/xxxxx?campaign={camp}&adgroup={publisher_id}&install_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{transaction}&session_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fpostback.example.com%3Ftransaction%3D{aff_sub1}&affsite={aff_site}&clickid={transaction}&adset_id={creative_id}&user_agent={ua}&ip={ip}&language={lang}";

var replaceTasks = new (string, string)[]
{
    ("camp", "campiagn_it_banner_size_360"),
    ("publisher_id", "78983"),
    ("transaction", "c1032072-f815-413b-a57c-4a027f681e60"),
    ("aff_sub1", "78bea32a-6ead-4ea0-b9f2-9489ebc43d6a"),
    ("aff_site", "vbvsdgdavhdgdvjs_46_789-p90"),
    ("creative_id", "360x360"),
    ("ua", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"),
    ("ip", "192.168.1.1"),
    ("lang", "en")
};
char prefix = '{';
char postfix = '}';
// the above are arguments to the funtion

int resultLength = -1;

string result = string.Create(origin.Length * 2, (replaceTasks, prefix, postfix), (chars, state) =>
{
    var replaceTasks = state.ReplaceTasksWithoutDelimiters;
    char prefix = state.prefix;
    char postfix = state.postfix;

    var position = 0;

    ReadOnlySpan<char> tmp = origin;

    int prefixIndex;
    while ((prefixIndex = tmp.IndexOf(prefix)) != -1)
    {
        bool replaced = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < replaceTasks.Length; i++)
        {
            // we expect the postfix to be at this place
            int postfixIndex = prefixIndex + replaceTasks[i].toReplace.Length + 1;
            if (tmp.Length > postfixIndex // check that we don't cross the bounds
                && tmp[postfixIndex] == postfix // check that the postfix IS were we expect it to be
                && tmp.Slice(prefixIndex + 1, postfixIndex - prefixIndex - 1).SequenceEqual(replaceTasks[i].toReplace)) // compare all the characters in between the delimiters
            {
                if (position + prefixIndex + replaceTasks[i].replaceWith.Length <= chars.Length) // check if the following copy operations would exceed our preallocated memory bounds
                {
                    tmp.Slice(0, prefixIndex).CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
                    replaceTasks[i].replaceWith.CopyTo(chars.Slice(position + prefixIndex));
                    position += prefixIndex + replaceTasks[i].replaceWith.Length;
                    tmp = tmp.Slice(postfixIndex + 1);
                    replaced = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!replaced) { // this delimiter is just part of the string, so skip it
            tmp.Slice(0, prefixIndex + 1).CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
            position += prefixIndex + 1;
            tmp = tmp.Slice(prefixIndex+ 1);
        }
    }

    if (position + tmp.Length <= chars.Length) // check if the following copy operation would exceed our preallocated memory bounds
    {
        // copy the remaining string
        tmp.CopyTo(chars.Slice(position));
        resultLength = position + tmp.Length;
    }
});

if (resultLength != -1)
{
    return result.Substring(0, resultLength); // there are many extrea null characters ('\0') at the end of our string, so we trim the string down
    
    // Note: the above realocates the string. if you can find a way to trim the string inplace, it should reduce the memory usage and speed a little.
}
else
{
    // the resulting string exceeded our preallocated memory. fallback to another method
    result = origin;

    for (int i = 0; i < ReplaceTasks.Length; i++)
    {
        (string toReplace, string replaceWith) = ReplaceTasks[i];
        result = result.Replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Of course when replacing only 1 token, this will be slower and use more memory than the builting method. On the other hand, the bigger the batch size, the bigger the speed and memory improvement (even if the tokens in the batch aren't in the origin string):

| Method | BatchSize | Mean | Ratio | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Normal** | **1** | **103.4 ns** | **1.00** | **736 B** | **1.00** |
| BatchDelimiterPreallocatedSafe | 1 | 154.4 ns | 1.49 | 2192 B | 2.98 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Normal** | **50** | **1,870.1 ns** | **1.00** | **8208 B** | **1.00** |
| BatchDelimiterPreallocatedSafe | 50 | 254.8 ns | 0.14 | 2560 B | 0.31 |